How to build a Xamarin Forms iOS app without a profile?
I would like to create .ipa or .app that will be signed later but I can't build it because of the missing profile.
I have already tried to ask chatgpt and others but no solution works.
I usually build .ipa using a profile and certificate but in this very specific case the profile and certificate will be provided by another company that can't share it with us.
